# Synchronize Data in Oracle with PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oop

the following "problem" :

2 Oracle Databases , Servers identified by their Names. If one attribute of the Server from Table X is different to Server in Table Y -> Update Table X.

What is the best solution ?

1. Fetch all Servers from both Databases and compare change them in an array ?
2. Get first Server from Table X , get Server from Table Y , Compare / Update
3. ??

I think the problem with number 2 is : I need a new connection for every entry ?
It would be fine if you have some nice ideas.

Think i have to explain : Iam not good in SQL and want to do this stuff with PHP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an 'old' problem (~50+ years)... you won't have to reinvent the wheel!

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965321/keeping-tables-synchronized-in-oracle) question on 'Keeping tables synchronized in Oracle' here on SO

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has all kind of replication options, there is no need for using PHP. Is one of the tables the master and the other the slave?

But why storing the same data twice? Can't you just use one database?

Comment: No because the "Source" Database is a little bit "messy(?)" so we have to double the data. Like : Dataset 1 has an nother Server OS like Dataset 2. Change Dataset1 , and create new OS in Keywordlist.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean? What is a keywordlist?