# Copy new records from one database to another

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

I have local and remote database.
The local database is a replica of remote database.
I have to insert new records from remote database into local database.
There are 14 tables in remote database, so i need to track changes in all 14 tables.

I know I can select every table in remote database and check if record exists in local database if not then insert it.

Is there another way to do it? In java maybe?
What approach would be the best?

Comment: I think the DBMS is more quick and safe, if you want to pass throw java, maybe this can take time, did you tryed dblink for example?

Comment: Speed is the least of the problems. Consider synchronization and consistency between the two DBs...

Comment: What are the data volumes ? 14 tables of a few hundred records is a different (and trivial) problem compared to 14 tables of a few billion records.

Comment: @Youcef Laidani - nope, but i'll try

Comment: what nope @user1598696, what you want to try?

Comment: @Gary Myers - there is 2-3 thousands of records each day, when that data is copied to local db and used(cards are made) - data in remote and local databases must be deleted. So there is constantly around 2-3 thousands of records

Comment: @Youcef Laidani  - I'll try dblink. I think i need synchronization, do you know which tools are simple to use?

Comment: i think there are a lot of subject, for eample you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420688/how-do-i-synchronize-two-oracle-databases or here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_admin002.htm#ADMIN12152 or here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm you can find a lot of things in google, i'm not professional in oracle but i worked with dblink in postgresql, and what i know that oracle is very good with bdlink

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with DBlink to remote DB

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK REMO
CONNECT TO <user_name>
IDENTIFIED BY <password>
USING '<service_name>';
```

then insert with loop over all tables from user schema. Or if you want insert only some tables please define proper condition for those 14 tables.

```
begin

for x in (select table_name from user_tables) loop
execute immediate 'insert into ' || x.table_name || ' (select * from ' || x.table_name || '@REMO minus select * from ' || x.table_name || ')';

commit;
end loop;
end;
/
```

This will insert only new records (in fact records that exists (or were changed) on remote and not exists on local). If taht's what you need this will work. If you need synchronisation this is not the solution.

Comment: IMHO: That is proper solution. It also, can be extended to some kind of "synchronization" solution to synchronize local DB with remote DB if it runs run periodically (as example).

Answer (score 1):

if you have only one local database and it runs all the time - you can use triggers from remote db to insert to the local db.

BTW: Go from local to check remote manually is not a good idea. What if existing remote record changed, but local still have old values?

Also there bunch of Oracle tools to make replications and synchronizations between databases. It is best to dig in it.

Comment: I' dont have access to remote db, only select, and update privileges are granted. Yes I think i need synchronization. Do you know which tools are the simplest to use?

Comment: I'm sorry I worked in that area quite long back and may not know latest. Anyway, techiques or tools there are for  DBA and you will not be able to apply them as a simple user (only with SELECT and UPDATE privileges).